# inheritance of viewholder class

Tags: java, android, generics, inheritance

I'm an android developer and I've got this issue regarding some OOP concepts in android. Whenever we create an adapter (lets take a recycler adapter ..) I usually do something like this:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<"MyAdapter.MyViewHolder">
{

    public MyAdapter(){}
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){}
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position){}
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{}
```

My question is in case we have our **MyViewHolder** as an internal class in our adapter (like written above....), why does it have to be declared as public/protected ?? Anytime I try to make the class private,I get an error at the top of the adapter class: **'packagename.MyAdapter.MyViewHolder has a private access in packagename.MyAdapter'**

Ever since i've been looking at tutorials (text or video) which explain how adapters work, they have never tried to explain why the MyViewHolder class needs to be declared as public. I really wanna understand this stuff.

Comment: I guess it’s because you are returning that type — that doesn’t make sense to do if the type is private. If any caller needs to know only that the result has type `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`, you can declare `public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder()` no matter is the object you return is really a `MyViewHolder`.

Comment: huuummmm......I guess u've got a point. Cuz the RecyclerView.Adapter class is public static and by making RecyclerView.Adapter<"MyAdapter.MyViewHolder"> we're actually generifying that class. But why does it now work when the MyViewHolder class is declared protected ??